# Articulations and Ornaments

Tags: articulation, french-horn, glissando, harp

I am currently studying some music scores, and I see some somethings that I don't know. I saw a French horn part that had a Plus (+) sign above it and it said "Stopped". I also saw a Harp Gliss. that said "L.V." and another that said "N.V." Can someone please tell me what these mean? Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Tim and welcome to the site. A picture would help a lot and to be of the most use to others it would be wise to separate each question into its own question as they are quite different

Answer (score 2):

'Stopping' on french horn is when you put your hand in the bell. This adjusts the pitch of the note and also has a muting effect. I am not an expert on this, however i found a good article on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_horn_techniques):

> This is the act of fully closing off the bell of the instrument with either the right hand or a special stopping mute. This results in producing a somewhat nasal sound. When required, in the sheet music the usual notation is a '+' above the note followed by a 'o' above notes that are to be played open. For longer stopped passages, the word indicating a stopped horn is written out.
>
> The pitch lowers gradually when the hand is placed in the bell and slowly moved inward. When the bell is completely covered (stopped), the pitch falls to a half-step above the next lower partial (harmonic).

As for the harp, a glissando is played with one or both hands. According to an E-Book i found [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=N01dmSAIKscC&pg=PA140&lpg=PA140&dq=harp%20gliss%20difference%20between%20V.V%20and%20L.V&source=bl&ots=SDRO5uTQD2&sig=ni-WLHmyQQvD5JfyGhdxeYxRg3w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_xsnn5MrOAhWILsAKHdqMDzsQ6AEIOjAF#v=onepage&q=harp%20gliss%20difference%20between%20V.V%20and%20L.V&f=false), L.V stands for `Let Vibrate`:

> If a natural sustain is desired and is not clear to the performer, indicate 'let vibrate' or L.V

At a guess, N.V means `no vibrate` or something along those lines.

I do not play either of these instruments, so if anyone who does wants to correct me, feel free to edit this post.

Answer (score 2):

Aric's answer is mostly correct, except that *l.v.* stands for *laissez vibrer* (French), strictly speaking. In this context, it simply means to allow the strings to ring for the duration of the glissando (and perhaps for longer afterwards too, if indicated). I've not seen *n.v.* before, but I would definitely interpret this as Aric did - as an explicit cancellation of *l.v.* (i.e. prevent the strings from ringing out over one another).